# in jsp, get realPath of deployed project

Tags: jsp, servlets

in servlet, as we can access the real path of deployed project

```
ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
string contextStr = context.getRealPath(".....");
```

How can i access the deployed project path in JSP page, any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%=request.getRealPath("write_your_file_name")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work just the same, for example by accessing `${pageContext.servletContext.getRealPath("...")}` to get the same results. JSP are nothing more than servlets after they got compiled.

Comment: Note: this construct is only supported since Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2.

Comment: Thats right. For less recent versions, @Bibhaw posted a valid solution. Thanks for clarifying, @BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

note, as of version 2.1 you should use

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("your_file_name")
```