# get path of deployed project on server

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to get  remote address or server address where my project is deployed. let suppose

```
http://www.myname.com/ : host

deployedProj : deployed web App name

folderName : there is a folder inside the web App

i want to access this address : http://www.myname.com/deployedProj/folderName
```

Comment: Didn't we just answer your question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646679/in-jsp-get-realpath-of-deployed-project

Comment: @Dirk: well that's working to fetch the static file path name e.g. C:\tomcat\webapp\myProject\folderName\

Comment: @Dirk: but i want to fetch the path name e.g. **http://localhost:8080/myProject/myFolder/**

Comment: Right. So, here you want to have access to the single parts of the URL from within a JSP?

Comment: yes Dirk, but i am little confuse because of new to java & servlet as well.

Comment: To acess the complete URL, try `<%= request.getRequestURL() %>`, myProject you get by `<%= request.getContextPath() %>` and so on. Have a look at the API-docs of [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Comment: @Dirk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1312/discussion-between-user744587-and-dirk)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do one thing by using requestDispatcher...

```
1.in servlet Action Class:  req.getRequestDispatcher("/your_WebApp_Name/folder_inside_project").forward(req,res);

e.g  req.getRequestDispatcher("/deployedProj/folderName").forward(req,res);

2. in JSP, 
 <%=request.getRequestURL()%>
```